# Python Global Hotkey

Tags: shortcut-keys, python, programming, python3

I'm looking to create a global hotkey in Python 3.2 for Ubuntu 12.10. That is, my script will run in the background and whenever I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> (for example), no matter what the active window is, the script will do something.

Some resources I have looked at:

- http://code.google.com/p/python-globalhotkeys/
- http://projects.gnome.org/deskbar-applet/ (source)
- http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/pyhook/ (for windows)
- http://python-xlib.sourceforge.net/
- http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/pykeylogger/

Maybe I am too much of a newb (I am a beginner) or I have been looking in the wrong places or for the wrong things, but, I haven't been able to utilize the resources above.

How can I create a global hotkey with Python 3.2 in Ubuntu 12.10. Thanks!

Comment: This seems like it'd fit better in a place like stackoverflow.

Comment: Suggestion acted on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13887921/python-global-hotkey I wont be offended if moderators delete this thread. Thank you Kupiakos for the heads up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this at X11/Xlib level. See this question for how to handle global hotkeys correctly in C: [Global Hotkey with X11/Xlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037230/global-hotkey-with-x11-xlib)

Now you only need some Python Xlib library; [python-xlib](http://python-xlib.sourceforge.net/) looks like a reasonable choice.

Comment: Through these links I eventually arrived at https://github.com/engla/keybinder It took some compiling to get it going, but I just ran one of the examples, and it worked! Thank You! very neat!

Answer (score 0):

I recenlty used [PyUserInput](https://github.com/PyUserInput/PyUserInput) for a similar task. It does the job really well and doesn't need compiling.